# Increasing Disk Read Throughput By Concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to read a log file and parse it that consumes only CPU. I have a server that reads a huge text file 230MB/second, just read text file not parse. When i try to parse the text file, using single thread, i can parse the file around 50-70MB/second.

I want to increase my throughput, doing that job concurrency. In this code, i reached 130 MB/second. At the peak, i saw 190MB/second. I tried BlockedQueue, Semaphore, ExecutionService etc. Is there any advice you give me reach at 200MB/second throughput.

```
public static void fileReaderTestUsingSemaphore(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CustomFileReader reader = new CustomFileReader(args[0]);
    final int concurrency = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(concurrency);
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(concurrency,true);
    System.out.println("Conccurrency in Semaphore: " + concurrency);


    String line;

    while ((line = reader.getLine()) != null)
    {
        semaphore.acquire();

        try
        {

            final String p = line;

            executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    reader.splitNginxLinewithIntern(p); // that is the method which parser string and convert to class.
                    semaphore.release();
                }
            });
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    System.out.println("ReadByteCount: " + reader.getReadByteCount());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit from the `Files.lines()` method and the Stream paradigm introduced in Java 8. It will use the systems common fork/join pool. Try this pattern:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class LineCounter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Files.lines(Paths.get("/your/file/here"))
             .parallel()
             .forEach(LineCounter::processLine);
    }

    private static void processLine(String line) {
        // do the processing
    }
}
```

Comment: My laptop (MacBook Pro mid 2015) will process a 450 MB file in a second from a cold start with this pattern...

Comment: Thank you for this code. This code is the best as for now. My parsing time is decreased to 130 seconds to 40 seconds. I hope i can fit this solution in my code.  @Per Huss :)

Comment: I'm happy to hear! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't care about order of lines:

```
    final String MARKER = new String(""); 
    BlockingQueue<String> q = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(1024);
    for (int i = 0; i < concurrency; i++)
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            for (;;) {
                try {
                    String s = q.take();
                    if(s == MARKER) {
                        q.put(s);
                        return;
                    }
                    reader.splitNginxLinewithIntern(s);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        q.put(line);
    }
    q.put(MARKER);
    executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This starts a number of threads that each runs a specific task; that task is to read from the queue and run the split method. The reader just feeds the queue, notifies when it's complete and waits for termination.

If you were to use RxJava2 and [rxjava2-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava2-extras) that would simply be

```
    Strings.from(reader)
           .flatMap(str -> Flowable
              .just(str)
              .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
              .doOnNext(reader::splitNginxLinewithIntern)
           )
           .blockingSubscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I tested your code, the result is the same. I tried this kind of code using ArrayBlockingQueue. I guess, i had better use chunked string array solitun that Ralf is mentioned. @Tassos

Answer (score 0):

You need to go multi-thread, and you need to have the reader thread delegate the parsing to worker threads, that's clear. The point is how to do this delegating with as little overhead as possible.

@Tassos provided code that looks like a solid improvement.

One more thing you can try is to change the delegation granularity, not delegating every single line individually, but building chunks of e.g. 100 lines, thus reducing the delegating/synchronizing overhead by a factor of 100 (but then needing a String[] array or similar, which shouldn't hurt too much).

Comment: Thank you for your message. I tested it. It improved a lot like my parsing time decreased 130 seconds to 70 seconds. But Per Huss solution is much better it decreased 40 seconds. @Ralf Kleberhoff